# MacOS Ventura can't give permissions (OpenCore)

Tags: macos, permissions, macbook-pro

I'm using 2013 mac with OpenCore Legacy Patcher. I recently updated to the Ventura 13.3.1 and had no problem until i realized i can't give special permissions to the applications. When i try to use microphone and camera from the Chrome or some other app, it automatically blocks the application from using them. And when i try to give permission from the settings window, i navigate to the Settings/Privacy&Security/Camera, the screen just shows this text:

```
Applications that have requested access to your camera will appear here.
```

I tried everything i can find in the internet but couldn't solve it. Lastly i tried to give permissions with the help of [tccplus](https://github.com/jslegendre/tccplus) but when i try to use it from the terminal, i get the error "zsh: permission denied ./tccplus".

I'd be appreciated if someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: What i see from the OpenCore app is that SIP is on (Lowered) mod. Currently configured SIP : 0x803

Comment: I fully enabled the SIP and rebooted from OpenCore, system crashed. I had to patch it from my USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I got it fixed:

Download tccplus and let it run in terminal

https://github.com/jslegendre/tccplus/releases/tag/1.0

Next run in terminal

codesign -dr -  (and drag and drop the app from finder)

So first find the app folder in finder where you see the app you want to assign  permissions to  and  in Terminal  type in “codesign -dr - “  (without the quotes of course) and drag the app e.g. Zoom or Teams and drop it right in the Terminal .

As result the path to the app wil be shown and press enter.
Next hit enter and see the result:

Here:

codesign -dr - /Applications/Microsoft\ Teams.app

(result)
Executable=/Applications/Microsoft Teams.app/Contents/MacOS/Teams
designated => identifier "com.microsoft.teams" and anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = UBF8T346G9
franknuninga@MacBook-Pro ~ %

com.microsoft.teams is the ID you need.

Next type in

cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x tccplus
./tccplus add Microphone [identifier]

So in this case

cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x tccplus
./tccplus add Microphone com.microsoft.teams

And hit enter

Terminal will return a confirmation.

Repeat the last command but replace Microphone with Camera

Comment: find the app id
codesign -dr - /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app

get Camera Permission

chmod +x tccplus
./tccplus add Camera com.google.Chrome    
get Mic permission

chmod +x tccplus 
./tccplus add Microphone com.google.Chrome


It works for me Ventura 13.4.1

Answer (score 3):

This is an OpenCore issue that's actually related to Apple Mobile File Integrity (AMFI), not SIP. Do **not** set SIP back to `On` or your computer won't boot. The macOS 13.3.x update broke a lot of things that worked in 13.2.x. I'd recommend joining the [OpenCore Patcher Paradise Discord Server](https://discord.gg/rqdPgH8xSN) to ask for help. They'll know exactly what you need to do. It may involve having to revert (or reinstall a fresh copy of) macOS 13.2.1 until other bugs can be worked out (that's what I had to do).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to give the permissions with tccplus ? Looks like other people can do it but for some reason i get the error "zsh: permission denied ./tccplus".

Answer (score 2):

The instructions above with `tccplus` worked for me - but I couldn't enter the commands in one line in terminal. Instead when I got to this part I entered:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
chmod +x tccplus
./tccplus add Microphone [identifier]
```

I used these as `[identifier]`:

- `us.zoom.xos` for Zoom
- `com.avid.ProTools` for Avid's audio software Pro Tools

Also, be sure and leave `tccplus` in the `downloads` folder for this to work - I had moved it to the desktop and quickly realized my mistake.

Comment: This worked for me. Had issues with camera and microphone permissions with skype